# Simple Rewrite rule with optional slash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

i would simply add a rewrite rule in my htaccess to have this :

http://mysite/toto -> http://mysite/page.php?c=toto

and the same result for:

http://mysite/toto/ -> http://mysite/page.php?c=toto

my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$  page.php?c=$1  [L]
```

It works with URL "http://mysite/toto"

but no with URL "http://mysite/toto/" --> result: http://mysite/page.php?c=toto/

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so you are running into a "greedy" match, the .* matches everything.  What you can do is get every character that is not a `/` with this:

^([^/]*).*

This says:

1. Match start `^`
2. Match any character except / :`[^/]`
3. Reference the step 2 match as $1 `the parens do that`

This will do what you want.  Note that if you have to escape the `/` character you will need to use /.  I do not think you need to with htaccess files.

Comment: I want the result to be the same for the user with or without the character "/".

Comment: OK, so use the rule `^(.*)$`, this will capture anything.

Comment: I try but it doesn't work for me.   
If the url is "mysite/toto/",  the result is "mysite/page.php?c=toto/". Or i want to have "mysite/page.php?c=toto"

Answer (score 1):

OK thank you!
I try this and it looks to work!

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ page.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]
```

url= http://localhost/toto/ --> result= http://localhost/page.php?c=toto

url= http://localhost/toto --> result= http://localhost/page.php?c=toto

Comment: Good, but if you have anything like:`http://localhost/toto/vovo` it will not match your regex.  Basically, anything after 1 slash at the end of your url will break it.

Comment: Exactly, i made a change.  

`RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)/([0-9]+)(.*)/?$ page.php?c=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]`  
and 

`RewriteRule ^sub/(.*[^/])/?$ page.php?c=$1 [QSA,L]`  

I need 2 parameters. this works well

Comment: so an url like `http://localhost/sub/toto/2034/vovo` is matched like `http://localhost/page.php?c=toto&id=2034`